# Custom plugin to move image around not moving image when src changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a jQuery plugin that has a plus/minus button to zoom into/out of an image, and allows the user to drag/move the image around within its container.

Snippet contains entire plugin code and minimum required html/css to recreate issue:

```js
/*!
 * jQuery Image Zoom v1
 * http://richard.parnaby-king.co.uk
 * https://github.com/richard-parnaby-king/jQuery-Image-Zoom
 */
//////////////////// Plugin /////////////////////
 ;( function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var pluginName = 'imageZoom',
        options = {
   scaleAmount:1.2, //(float) amount to zoom in / out by
   zoomInText:'+', //(string) Text to show in span for zoom in button
   zoomOutText:'-'  //(string) Text to show in span for zoom out button
        };

    function ImageZoom( element, opts ) {
        this.element = element;
        this._name = pluginName;
        options = $.extend( {}, options, opts );


  //local variables
  var link = this.element.find('a'),
   bigImage = link.attr('href'),
   image = this.element.find('img'),
   currentScale = 1,
   mouseDown = false,
   ix = 0,
   iy = 0,
   sWidth,sHeight;
    
  this.image = image;
  this.link = link;
  link.on('click.' + pluginName, function(e){e.preventDefault();});
  this.element.addClass('imageZoom-holder');
   
  image.on('load',function(){
   image.css({
    '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(1)',
    '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(1)',
    '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(1)',
    '-o-transform'      : 'scale(1)',
    'transform'         : 'scale(1)',
    'top'    : '0',
    'left'    : '0'
   });
   sWidth = image.width();
   sHeight = image.height();
   image.attr('src',bigImage);
   image.width(sWidth);
   image.height(sHeight);
  });
   
  //add buttons to image
  this.element.append('<div class="imageZoom-buttons"><span class="zoomInButton" unselectable="on">'+options.zoomInText+'</span><span class="zoomOutButton" unselectable="on">'+options.zoomOutText+'</span></div>');
  var buttons = this.element.find('.imageZoom-buttons');
   
  //when click on zoom in/out buttons, scale image accordingly
  buttons.find('.zoomInButton').on('click.' + pluginName,function(){
   currentScale *= options.scaleAmount;
   image.css({
    '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')',
    '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')',
    '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')',
    '-o-transform'      : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')',
    'transform'         : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')'
   });
  });
  buttons.find('.zoomOutButton').on('click.' + pluginName,function(){
   //make image smaller, but do not allow image to be made smaller than original size
   if(currentScale > 1) {
    currentScale /= options.scaleAmount;
    image.css({
     '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')',
     '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')',
     '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')',
     '-o-transform'      : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')',
     'transform'         : 'scale(' + currentScale + ')'
    });
   } else {
    //if image is original size, position image back into centre
    image.css({'left':0,'top':0});
   }
  });
   
  this.buttons = buttons;
   
  //when click/drag on image, move image
  image.on('mousedown.' + pluginName + ' touchstart.' + pluginName,function(e){
   ix = e.pageY,
   iy = e.pageX;
   if(e.originalEvent instanceof TouchEvent) {
    ix = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    iy = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
   }
   mouseDown = true;
   return false;
  });
  image.on('mouseup.' + pluginName + ' touchend.' + pluginName + ' touchcancel.' + pluginName,function(e){
   mouseDown = false;
  });
  image.on('mousemove.' + pluginName + ' touchmove.' + pluginName,function(e){
   if(e.originalEvent instanceof TouchEvent) {
    e.pageX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    e.pageY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
   }
   if(mouseDown == true) {
    var offsetLeft = parseInt( image.css('left').replace(/[^0-9\.\-]+/,'') |0 ) - ( iy - e.pageX ),
     offsetTop = parseInt( image.css('top').replace(/[^0-9\.\-]+/,'') |0 ) - ( ix - e.pageY );
    
    //move image
    image.css( 'left', offsetLeft );
    image.css( 'top', offsetTop );
    iy = e.pageX;
    ix = e.pageY;
   }
  });
    };

    ImageZoom.prototype.destroy = function(){
  this.image.off('.' + pluginName);
  this.buttons.off('.' + pluginName);
  this.element.find('.imageZoom-buttons').remove();
  this.element.removeData();
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function( options ){
  return this.each( function() {
   if( !$.data( this, pluginName )) {
    $.data( this, pluginName, new ImageZoom ( $(this), options ));
   }
  });
    }

} )( jQuery, window, document );


/////////////// End Plugin ////////////////////
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main').imageZoom();
 $('.extra a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var image = $('.main'),
   $this = $(this);
  image.data('imageZoom').destroy();
  image.find('a').attr('href',$this.attr('href')).find('img').attr('src',$this.attr('href'));
  image.imageZoom();
 });
  });
```

```css
div.main {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
.imageZoom-holder {
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}
.imageZoom-holder .imageZoom-buttons {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
.imageZoom-holder .imageZoom-buttons span {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:1em;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:1em;
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
.imageZoom-holder img {
 -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s linear;
 -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.3s linear;
 -ms-transition:-ms-transform 0.3s linear;
 -o-transition:-o-transform 0.3s linear;
 transition:transform 0.3s linear;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="extra">
 <a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/b806b8/ffffff&text=1"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x100/b806b8/ffffff&text=1"></a>
 <a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/111111&text=2"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x100/ffffff/111111&text=2"></a>
</div>
```

My issue is that when I change the image (click on one of the small thumbnails under the main image), the src of the image is changed, but the move feature stops working - the image will jutter around a little bit, but fundamentally does not move position.

What part of my plugin is causing the image to not move?

Comment: Interestingly, when I open and close developer tools in chrome the images become movable. This is bizarre!

Comment: Also noticed that the scaling has also stopped working.

Comment: Please comment WHY you are voting close! Saying it's off-topic is not helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in:

```
image.on('load',function(){
    image.css({ 
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

This function is called infinitely. I think it's because in this function you modify `src` attribute of the image and the load event fires again.

```
image.on('load',function(){
    console.log('Hi!!');
    image.css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(1)',
        '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(1)',
        '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(1)',
        '-o-transform'      : 'scale(1)',
        'transform'         : 'scale(1)',
        'top'               : '0',
        'left'              : '0'
    });
    sWidth = image.width();
    sHeight = image.height();
    image.attr('src',bigImage);  
    image.width(sWidth);
    image.height(sHeight);
});
```

I don't know why you attach this code to load event. I think it should be executed every time the image changes and ImageZoom is called. It works ok if you don't attach it:

```
// image.on('load',function(){
    image.css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(1)',
        '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(1)',
        '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(1)',
        '-o-transform'      : 'scale(1)',
        'transform'         : 'scale(1)',
        'top'               : '0',
        'left'              : '0'
    });
    sWidth = image.width();
    sHeight = image.height();
    image.attr('src',bigImage);
    image.width(sWidth);
    image.height(sHeight);
// });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a29v1e6a/1/)

Comment: I put on load in because sometimes the js would run before the image had finished loading. As such, the variables `sWidth` and `sHeight` would be set to 0.

Comment: I understand, but the `load` event on images does not always works as expected. Look at [jQuery .load() API](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) in "Caveats of the load event when used with images" section.

Comment: What can I do as an alternative?

Comment: Perhaps [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin can be helpful for you.